# Programmatically cycle power on WinCE 5 PCMCIA socket?

Tags: windows-ce

How can a WinCE 5 driver cycle the power on a PCMCIA socket under its control?

I have tried [CardPowerOff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447630.aspx)() in pcmcia.dll, but it doesn't actually remove power.  Any advice there would be helpful, but I'm not picky about the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the mechanism to achieve it is hardware/OEM dependant.  You're going to have to go to your device OEM and ask them if/how it might be done on their hardware.  My guess is that if CardPowerOff isn't actually removing card power, the OEM didn't provide a way to fully shut it down (I've seen them hard wired to power before).

Comment: Thanks.  That's helpful to know.  Do you happen to know how HP tends to handle CardPowerOff()?  We're using the iPaq 210.